# Sending telemetry to ApplicationInsights inside ConfigureServices

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-application-insights

I'd like to send some telemetry from within ConfigureServices, for example if I'm missing a config setting I'd like to send an event to AI to track this.

```
public class Startup
{
   public void ConfigureServices( IServiceCollection services)
   {
      services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();

      // Is there a way of getting the telemetry client here to send some telemetry?
      // e.g. TelemetryClient.TrackEvent("MyEvent");
   }
}
```

Is there any way of getting hold of the telemetry client created by `AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry` within ConfigureServices? Is the context even valid at that point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, we cannot get hold of the telemetry client created by `AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry` within `ConfigureServices` before `ConfigureServices` method is finished.

You should manually create a telemetry client for your purpose in `ConfigureServices` method, like below:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    var s1 = services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration["APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY"]);

    TelemetryConfiguration configuration = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();
    configuration.InstrumentationKey = Configuration["APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY"];
    var telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(configuration);

    telemetryClient.TrackEvent("xxx");
}
```